# Shape no se aplica correctamente

Tags: android

Quiero poner este shape a mi boton pero no se esta aplicando correctamente, ya que en el medio queda un rectángulo en blanco que no deja mostrar los bordes del shape.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

<stroke android:color="#aaaaa"
   android:width="10dp" />

<padding android:left="50dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="50dp"
    android:bottom="1dp"/>

<corners android:radius="50dp"/>
   </shape>


   <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/search_group"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_part3"
      />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas definiendo un color invalido en el stroke, debe ser android:color="#aaaaaa".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te explico cual es el problema estas utilizando mal el color "#aaaaa" o usas una notación de 3 dígitos o una de 6 como hiciste con el color blanco esto causa el error que estas viendo. si usas android studio asegurate que el color se vea en la columna de guia en la izquierda. utiliza el siguiente codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

    <stroke android:color="#aaaaaa"
        android:width="10dp" />

    <padding
        android:left="50dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

Despues que lo cambies refresca la vista muchas veces demora en refrescar te recomiendo cerrarla y abrirla otra vez o utilizar el boton de refresh en el android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Jorge, el problema con el [shape](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html) es que **estas definiendo en `stroke` un color invalido** :

```
<stroke android:color="#aaaaa"
```

lo cual provoca esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debe ser:

```
<stroke android:color="#aaaaaa"
```

Este es el [shape](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html) corregido:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

    <stroke android:color="#aaaaaa"
        android:width="10dp" />

    <padding android:left="50dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

para obtener lo que deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Otra opción es realizar esto mediante una imagen **[9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)**, la cual simplemente definirías como `background`:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/search_group"
    android:background="@drawable/ninepatchimage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_part3"
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Estás seguro de que no hay nada más de código que afecte a ese botón? Yo he usado tu shape sobre el mismo botón y se me muestra correctamente. Este es el código que yo he usado para el botón:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.usuario.usuario.pruebashape.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="BUSCAR"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_part3"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y esta la shape que he usado:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

    <stroke android:color="#aaaaaa"
        android:width="10dp" />

    <padding android:left="50dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

El resultado ha sido este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes comprobar es el mismo código que el tuyo solo que en vez de usar un string para el nombre de "BUSCAR" lo pongo directamente. Por lo tanto, se me ocurren dos cosas que pueden estar haciendo que tu botón se vea con un rectángulo blanco:

1. Que en tu `@string/search_group` le estés dándo alguna carácterística adicional al mensaje de "BUSCAR" como por ejemplo un padding.
2. Que estés modificando ese botón mediante código.

Por favor, revisa que no estés modificando el botón desde ningún otro sitio.